# How do I generate a List<List<Double>> with apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, xsd, cxf

I'm trying to generate a `List<List<Double>>` with apache cxf.

The following xsd generates a `List<Double>`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Geometry">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="type" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="coordinates" minOccurs="1">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:list>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:list itemType="xsd:double"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:list>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If I add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the element coordinates, I get a `List<JAXBElement<List<Double>>> coordinates`

How can I generate a `List<List<Double>>`?

Answer (score 0):

the schema says coordinates can contain a list of list of doubles, which basically means a list of doubles.

changing maxoccurs="unbounded" will significantly change the XML

```
<coordinates>1 2 3</coordinates>
```

could now be

```
<coordinates>1</coordinates>
<coordinates>2 3</coordinates>
```

Whats been generated so far look correct, what are you trying to make the XML look like?

Comment: Actually I'm generating a java class with wadl2java which represents the output of my webservice. This is for a geoJson field in my webservice's response : {"type":"", "coordinates":[[0;0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]]}

Comment: OK, I think I'm missing something, your trying to generate json output using an xml schema (XSD) as the meta data. Wheres the XSD come from? If the output is json, do you have a json schema?